# Using JS id in dropdown - works from text file but not from a php variable string

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, string

I am using an HHTML form with a dropdown which is populated from a JS script through id.

```
<div class="ui-widget">
             <input id="ctags" class="form-control col-md-8" autocomplete="off" 
             placeholder="Start typing Collection Town" name="colltown_name" required>  
             <input id="ctag" type="hidden" name="colltown">
            </div>
```

The JS script to create the id "ctags" is as follows using a .txt file

```
<script>  //AUTOCOMPLETE FOR TOWNS - MOBILE FRIENDLY
      (function() {
        
        var towns = [<?php echo file_get_contents("file.txt")?>];
            
                    
        $("#ctags").autocomplete({
            source: towns,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $("#ctags").val(ui.item.label);
                $("#ctag").val(ui.item.value);
                return false;
            }
        });
  </script>
```

This dropdown populates and works as should, but I want to rather use a PHP SELECT statement to retrieve the information every time and generate a fresh list for the towns, as the information does change periodically. I have created the PHP SELECT section and it generates a PHP variable which is a string, that is identical to the txt file. I have checked this through console.log.
So the PHP code to take the array returned from the SELECT statement is as follows.
I have added str_replace to make sure that the string is identical to the txt file and $towns_dropdown is the array returned from the SELECT statement.

```
    <?php 
    $netJSON = json_encode($towns_dropdown);
    $net = str_replace("[","",$netJSON);
    $net1 = str_replace("]","",$net);
    ?>
```

I then change my JS to create the id "ctags" as follows using a PHP variable instead of the txt file.

```
<script>  //AUTOCOMPLETE FOR TOWNS - MOBILE FRIENDLY
      (function() {
        
        var towns='<?php echo $net1; ?>';
            
                    
        $("#ctags").autocomplete({
            source: towns,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $("#ctags").val(ui.item.label);
                $("#ctag").val(ui.item.value);
                return false;
            }
        });
    </script>
```

If I read results in console.log it displays the string, but the dropdown doesn't populate.
If I get the PHP create to create a new file from the PHP variable and then call that file (file.txt) in the JS script as follows:-

```
    <?php 
    $netJSON = json_encode($towns_dropdown);
    $net = str_replace("[","",$netJSON);
    $net1 = str_replace("]","",$net);
    $file = 'file.txt';
    $data = $net1;
    file_put_contents($file, $data);
    ?>
```

it populates the dropdown correctly

So JS calls the new file file.txt and it works, as in populating the dropdown.

So, in conclusion, I don't seem to be able to get a PHP variable(which is a string) to get the dropdown to populate.......

Comment: What format does your JS _expect_? We can’t tell what `var towns = [<?php echo file_get_contents("file.txt")?>];` actually produces, because we don’t know what your text file contains.

Comment: Use `var towns =  ["<?= file_get_contents("file.txt")?>"]` instead of what are you writing ! ... Just warp your php with string ""

Comment: This is what file.txt looks like:-
{ "label": "AANDRUS, Bloemfontein", "value": 1 },
{ "label": "AANHOU WEN, Stellenbosch", "value": 2 },
{ "label": "ABBOTSDALE, Western Cape", "value": 3 },
{ "label": "ABBOTSFORD, East London", "value": 4 },
{ "label": "ABBOTSFORD, Johannesburg", "value": 5 },
{ "label": "ABBOTSPOORT, Limpopo", "value": 6 },
{ "label": "ABERDEEN, Eastern Cape", "value": 7 },
{ "label": "ACKERVILLE, Witbank", "value": 8 },
{ "label": "ACORNHOEK, Mphumalanga", "value": 9 },
{ "label": "ACTIVIA PARK, Germiston", "value": 10 }

Comment: You JSON shenanigans there are wildly absurd. “Stripping off” the `[` and `]` from a JSON-encoded value, that is pretty huge nonsense. If your JS part expects the data as an array - then have your PHP script populate an array, and then pass the JSON-encoded version of it to the JS, without manipulating it & cutting bits off.

Comment: _“This is what files.txt looks like”_ - so with the `[` and `]` you _manually_ put around this, this would be an array of objects. So, fill the appropriate array in PHP, and then encode it as JSON, without whittling away at it afterwards.

Comment: @CBroe, yip, I stripped out the square brackets to exactly copy the txt file as that format works.

Comment: _“I stripped out the square brackets to exactly copy the txt file as that format works.”_ - you put them around your text file content yourself, but with your second version, you removed them in that place, `var towns='<?php echo $net1; ?>';`, _and_ you removed them from the JSON contained in `$net1` as well … so where from did you expect to _get them back_ now?

Comment: @CBroe - the txt file which works does not have the square brackets. So, I tried removing them from the default variable created by PHP to duplicate the working txt format. The dropdown doesn't work in the default PHP json encode variable, nor the "butchered" version.

Comment: _“the txt file which works does not have the square brackets”_ - yes, but you did add them around that, with `var towns = [<?php echo … ?>];`. So of course you need to match that format, achieve the same end result, with your modified version now. So, create the corresponding array data structure in PHP, encode it as JSON - and output it. _Without_ putting an extra set of [] around it, because those will come from the JSON encoding already now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working using the PHP variable as follows:-

```
<?php 
$towns_list = json_encode($towns_dropdown);
    ?>
```

and the JS script line:-

```
var towns=<?php echo $towns_list; ?>;
```

@CBroe, you were correct, I was getting confused in the JSON shennanigans, once I saw through that it was pretty straight forward.